# MySQL está duplicando resultado de pesquisar

Tags: mysql

Estou tendo dificuldades para montar uma query.

Eu tenho uma Banco de Dados mais ou menos nessa estrutura.

Tabela1
Tabela2
Tabela3
Tabela4

Preciso montar uma query que pegue os resultados nas 4 tabelas, para isso eu usei o LEFT JOIN, porque nas tabelas2, 3 e 4 pode ser que não exista.

Fiz uma query assim:

```
select distinct id_tabela1,
tid_tabela2, tid_tabela3, tid_tabela4 
from tabela1 t1  
left join tabela2 t2 on t1.id_tabela1 = t2.tid_tabela2 
left join tabela3 t3 on t1.id_tabela1 = t3.tid_tabela3 
left join tabela4 t4 on t1.id_tabela1 = t4.tid_tabela4 
where...
```

O que está acontecendo é o seguinte, as tabelas 2, 3 e 4 podem ter id's diferentes com valores diferentes, mas associada ao id da tabela1 e isso está duplicando o id da tabela1 no resultado da pesquisa.

Um exemplo de como esta saindo:

```
id_tabela1 | tid_tabela2 | tid_tabela3 | tid_tabela4
1          | x           | null        | null
1          | z           | null        | null
```

O que eu preciso, é que esse 'Z' saia na mesma linha do 'X'.

É possível isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar o [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) para agrupar e concatenar a sua string da seguinte forma.

```
select id_tabela1, GROUP_CONCAT(tid_tabela2 SEPARATOR ' ') as tid_tabela2 
, GROUP_CONCAT(tid_tabela3 SEPARATOR ' ') as tid_tabela3  ,  GROUP_CONCAT(tid_tabela4 SEPARATOR ' ') as tid_tabela4 
from tabela1 t1  
left join tabela2 t2 on t1.id_tabela1 = t2.tid_tabela2 
left join tabela3 t3 on t1.id_tabela1 = t3.tid_tabela3 
left join tabela4 t4 on t1.id_tabela1 = t4.tid_tabela4 
where... seu filtro
group by id_tabela1
```

Comment: O GROUP_CONCAT deu certo, porém eu cai em outro problema.
Lá na tabela2, por exemplo, eu tenho um campo chamado status que ele pode vir como 'Null', sendo assim o resultado da pesquisa está saindo mais ou menos assim:
tid1 tid2 | status
se o campo for 'Null' ele não concatena do modo correto e eu não consigo identificar se esse status é do TID1 ou do TID2.

Comment: Eu não sei como você esta usando o campo status, mas você pode tenta usa o [NULLIF(status,'')](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html)

Comment: Consegui assim: GROUP_CONCAT(ifnull(c.arp, 'null') SEPARATOR '&') arp .
O problema só é que esse campo pode ser vazio ou nulo... Então tenho que achar uma forma de transformar os campos vazios em 'null' no resultado.

Comment: Não entendi você quer verificar as duas condições? S3 é Null ou vazio

Comment: Veja se ajuda com isso ,http://stackoverflow.com/a/17832946/2740371  `SELECT IF(field1 IS NULL or field1 = '', 'empty', field1) as field1 
from tablename`

Comment: Deu certo sim, a ideia era fazer o seguinte...
Por exemplo, a pesquisa retornava com o 'tid1&tid2' | 'status1&status2', eu quero associar ao status1 ao tid1 e o status2 ao tid2 via PHP dando um explode. Porém se o primeiro valor fosse vazio ele concatenava assim: &status2, então o explode não funcionava do jeito que eu queria

O comando ficou assim: GROUP_CONCAT(IF(c.arp IS NULL OR c.arp = '', 'null', c.arp) SEPARATOR '&') arp,

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!